# How remove symbols from the sentence in Oracle?

Tags: sql, database, oracle

In **Oracle** database I have such table.

```
| TREE                            | ORG_NAME |
|---------------------------------|----------|
| \Google earth\Nest global\ATAP  | ATAP     |
| \Google earth\Nest\Beemoney\    | Beemoney |
| \Google\\\BeeKey\               |          |
|                                 | York     |
```

I am trying to make sql query which would return such result.

```
| ORGANIZATION                      |
|-----------------------------------|
| Google earth > Nest global > ATAP |
| Google earth > Nest Beemoney      |
| Google > BeeKey                   |
| York                              |
```

As you can see I want:

1) Replace `\` symbol at the beginning and end of the sentence.

2) Replace `\` symbol which is inside sentence to `>` symbol.

3) Replace `\\\` symbol which is inside sentence to `>` symbol.

4) If `TREE` colomn is empty take record from `ORG_NAME` colomn.

Here is how I started. This SQL query solve 2, 3 and 4 part. How to solve problem with 1 part. I think I need to use `REGEXP_REPLACE`, right? How to make it correctly? Is there any other more elegant way to redisign sql query? As you can see I walk on the same table a few times.

```
SELECT
    COALESCE (TREE, ORG_NAME) as ORGANIZATION
FROM (
    SELECT
        REPLACE(TREE, '\', '>') AS TREE,
        ORG_NAME
    FROM (
        SELECT
            REPLACE(TREE, '\\\', '>') AS TREE,
            ORG_NAME
        FROM
            ORG
    )
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be a way with a `regexp_replace` and a `trim` to remove the characters from the beginning and the end of the string:

```
select nvl(regexp_replace( trim('\' from tree), '\\+', ' > '), org_name)
from yourTable
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Can I ask you one more question? Is it possible also to replace `\t` (`tab`) also to `>` symbol?

Comment: An easy way could be by wrapping this with a replace, considering that chr(9) is the tab character

Comment: For example how to add such logic to your code `SELECT REPLACE(TREE, chr(9),  ' > ') FROM ORG;`?

Comment: You need to wrap the part I wrote; so something like `REPLACE(nvl(regexp_replace( trim('\' from tree), '\\+', ' > '), org_name), chr(9), ' > ')`

Answer (score 2):

Here is a working solution which uses two calls to `regexp_replace`:

```
select
    regexp_replace(
        regexp_replace('\Google\\\BeeKey\', '^\\?(.*?)\\?$', '\1'), '\\+', ' > ')
from dual;

Google > BeeKey
```

### Demo

The inner call to `regexp_replace` strips off any possible leading or trailing path separators.  The outer call converts any number of internal path separators `/` to `>` separators as a replacement.